# UITableViewCell doesn't show it's content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working a UITableViewController with a dynamic TableView, which displays some information about a dish. Everything is working fine, but one cell just stays blank.

When I debug the code, all things look like expected (tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: gets called for each portion in self.menuItem.menuPortions, portion isn't nil and  values of it's properties are valid, the UILabels aren't nil either), but the first portionCell stays empty, no matter how much portions self.menuItem.menuPortions holds...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:{//image
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIImageView* imageView = ((UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1]);
            [self.menuItem setImageOfImageView:imageView OrDeleteCellAtIndexPath:indexPath fromTable:tableView];
            break;}
        case 1:{//description
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"descriptionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            UITextView * descriptionTextView = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            descriptionTextView.text = self.menuItem.menuItemDescription;
            break;}
        case 2:{//portions
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"portionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            id<MenuItemPortionProtocol> portion = self.menuItem.menuPortions[indexPath.row];

            UILabel * sizeLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            sizeLabel.text = portion.size;

            UILabel * priceLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
            priceLabel.text = [portion priceString];
            break;}
        case 3:{//categories
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"categoriesCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            UILabel* categoriesLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            categoriesLabel.text = [self.menuItem.categories componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
            break;}
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}
```

Does someone have a hint, what goes wrong?

Comment: and what exactly is `id<MenuItemPortionProtocol> portion` you problem is there!

Comment: No it isn't there. When I set a break point on `case 2:`, `self.menuPortions[indexPath.row]` always returns a valid (not nil, `[portion priceString]` and portion.size are NSStrings with length > 0) object implementing the `id<MenuItemPortionProtocol>`. So I am really sure there is no problem with portion.

Comment: have you logged it `if(indexPath.row==0)NSLog(@"menuPortions=%@",self.menuItem.menuPortions[indexPath.row];);`

Comment: Yes... The output is just fine...

Comment: I just tested the app on a real device and here everything seems to work fine... Does someone have an idea?